# How to create xpath for backtracking to parent node from child node

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

[image: Please find the DOM]

Currently my requirement is to check the check box at class="ui-checkbox seyc-cell-checkBox-div".
The input which I have is the supplier description present at id="cellDocument2_matrix_block_0_1"

Could you please let me know how to create a Xpath for selecting the check box using the text

Comment: Add HTML sample as simple text, not as image... Also add you current XPath

Comment: Update the question with text based formatted _HTML_ along with your code trials

Answer (score 0):

Found an xpath :

```
$x("//*[contains(text(),'description')]//ancestor::a/div/div[1]")
```

Do let me know, incase of any other better approach for location checkbox

Comment: Target div on provided image doesn't contain text `"description"`. Do you need to match ancestor of div with text `"FOURNISSEUR..."` or which one?

Comment: I have to select the radio button ( highlighted at first line of screenshot) based on the text ( highlighted at the end of the screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

`"../"` will take you one level up. So for example, you are on certain element and you want to navigate 3 levels up in hierarchy you would have to do `element.FindElement(By.xpath(../../..));`